# Using grunt-connect-proxy with latest version of Yeoman generated angular Project

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am very new to grunt

We are trying to configured grunt-contrib-livereload for our angular project that we run on latest version of Grunt

We followed the configuration instruction to add the below code using livereload configuration

```
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;
```

..
..
..

```
 livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            proxySnippet,
                            lrSnippet,
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                        ];
                    }
                }
           },
```

However on reading more grunt-contrib-livereload is replaced by watch and thus I was not able to resolve the below line of code

var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib/utils').livereloadSnippet;

So I wanted to know if lrSnippet is required in the above configuration. I removed it and done the configuration as below and it works but wanted to know if there is something wrong with below

```
 livereload: {
                options: {
                    middleware: function (connect) {
                        return [
                            proxySnippet,
                           // lrSnippet, // Find out how to solve this
                            mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                            mountFolder(connect, 'app')

                        ];
                    }
                }
            }
```

commented out the lrSnipped section. Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with removing lrSnippet as it is now deprecated and handled inside watch. So as long as you have livereload in your watch, then it will work fine.